# Turkish soldier with ISIS?

Tags: politics, isis, turkey

Oliver North posted this image on [twitter](https://twitter.com/OliverNorthFNC/status/520664937455038464) and wrote

> A Turkish soldier "visiting" an ISIS anti-aircraft unit at Kobani.
>   They look way too friendly.

[image: Oliver North]

Is the description of the image correct?

Comment: just saw this discussion http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/handling-news-questions-about-current-events/2870#2870 ...

Comment: the outcome of that discussion seems to be that this question shouldn't be closed, though you also shouldn't be surprised if it doesn't get answers for a while. I suspect a rebuttal might be possible now if someone found an original photo that this was taken from, but a confirmation would probably take quite a while

Comment: There seem to be no contention that the image is genuine (not photoshopped). What we have is a claim with a single source about current news. This is not really answerable with evidence yet. If you want to ask whether Turkey and ISIS are truly enemies, then we need to wait for some historical consensus.